# Create a function that prints out the number of positive integers parsed in args

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having problems executing this program in which I have to enable Java to return the amount of Positive numbers in an array of integers already typed in the line of command.

```
public class A1Q1 {

    private static int countPositive(int[] array) {

        int positive = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > 0) {
                positive = positive + 1;
            }
            System.out.println(positive);
        }
        return positive;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = new int[]{5, 6, 7, 45, -2, -9};
        int count = countPositive(array);
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code contains multiple errors related to brackets. For instance, you never close your `countPositive` method, your main method is inside a for-loop inside another method...

Comment: I like how you write code with errors but then don't even tell us what the errors are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program have many problem try this code :

```
private static int countPositive(int[] array) {

    int positive = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) { //should be greater than 0  
            positive++;
        }
    }
    return positive;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] array = new int[]{5, 6, 7, 45, -2, -9};
    int count = countPositive(array);
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

**First**

If you are in the same class you don't need to instantiate it again

like this you do here:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        A1Q1 nt = new A1Q1();
```

**Second**

You should use the same name of method in your loop:

```
 //-----------------------------------this name--
 private static int countPositive(int[] array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

You can start java here:

[Getting started](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)

And about array :

[Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Not to mention that the method countPositive is actually counting negatives. Either name it `countNegative` or change the if-condition to `array[i] > 0`

Comment: thank you @ViniciusVictor i think i reject your edit because i edit it in the same time, you can edit it again if you want

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions but in return it gives me: 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 instead of the amount of positives in the arraylist.

Comment: yes @Zinedin because you are using `System.out.println(positive);` in your method `countPositive`, so just delete it, i already delete it, now your will get only 4

Comment: Yeah I see that, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 or before:

```
private static int countPositive(int[] array) {
    int positive = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            positive = positive + 1;
        }
    }
    return positive;
}
```

Java 8 version:

```
private static int countPositive(int[] array) {
    return (int) Arrays.stream(array).filter(number -> number > 0).count();
}
```

No changes in main method.